# What's the difference between SYSOUT and SYSPRINT of a job?

Tags: jcl

While coding a `JCL`, we give `SYSOUT` and `SYSPRINT` `DD`s. Which type of output goes to `SYSOUT` and what else to `SYSPRINT`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SYSOUT is always allocated and gets among other things all the output from the System level process (including any messages about the JCL itself, performance stats, error messages etc.)

SYSPRINT is just another DD which, by convention, is used by utility programs for thier output.

Comment: James! Thanks for your response. Have a question here.. JCL related messages like allocation/deallocation messages, performance stats, error messages etc will be displayed JESMSG of JCL spool right... Please clarify of lemme know if i missed something..

Comment: The JES (Job Entry Subsystem) is a separate piece of software from the job initiator (which is what writes to SYSOUT) and its outputs are directed to JESMSG. Are you on JES II or JES III?

Answer (score 3):

sysout : To print the output of the program in spool,it is a system defined program.

sysprint : To print messages of the program execution, and ii contains compile source listing and line no, offset no.

Answer (score 1):

Historically, IBM utility programs used SYSOUT for status messages, and used SYSPRINT for the utility program reports.

In COBOL programs, the output of DISPLAY statements goes to SYSOUT.

JCL related messages from a JES system are written to JESMSG.  (Not sure of the spelling.  I'm at home now, not at work.)

Answer (score 1):

**SYSOUT** system defined dd name used for file status codes and system abend codes information and output of the display statement can be viewd

and sysout parameter used to direct the output device and genarete during execution of the job to an output device

**SYSPRINT** contains the compiled source listing and for each line in the soucrce listing a line number and offset no can be genarated